# sympy: post order traversal over expression tree: skips top-level operation

Tags: sympy, expression-trees, postorder

I am trying to loop post order through a sympy-expression.
It works fine except for the fact that it skips the last addition (im my example case the addition of `sympy.sin(x * y)` and `z**2`).

```
import sympy

def post(expr):
    if not expr:
        return
    for arg in expr.args:
        post(arg)
        print(f'arg {arg}')
        print(f'arg.func: {arg.func}')
        print(f'arg.args: {arg.args}')

x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x,y,z')
expr = sympy.sin(x * y) + z**2
post(expr)
```

I think it's because of the `for arg in expr.args` part yet if I ditch the `.args` and
loop over the whole expression

```
import sympy

def post(expr):
    if not expr:
        return
    for arg in expr:
        post(arg)
        print(f'arg {arg}')
        print(f'arg.func: {arg.func}')
        print(f'arg.args: {arg.args}')

x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x,y,z')
expr = sympy.sin(x * y) + z**2
post(expr)
```

I get `TypeError: 'Add' object is not iterable`.
Can I somehow fix this such that it loops over all functions of the expression and doesn't skip the top-level function?

Comment: Wait, you already know that you need to use `args` to iterate over a `Add` object.  Why did you remove it?

Comment: Why didn't you show some, if not all of the `prints`?  I can't run `sympy` code in my head.

Comment: OK, I ran your code, and got the prints.  What you are missing is a top level print of `expr, expr.func, expr.args`, the `expr` itself, before any iteration.

Comment: In other words, do the prints before the iteration, not within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This battery is already included if you want to use it:

```py
from sympy.core.traversal import postorder_traversal
for i in postorder_traversal(expr):print(i)
```

gives

```
z
2
z**2
x
y
x*y
sin(x*y)
z**2 + sin(x*y)
```

Otherwise, consider this modification for your function:

```py
def post(expr):
    for arg in expr.args:
        post(arg)
    print(f'arg {expr}')
    print(f'arg.func: {expr.func}')
    print(f'arg.args: {expr.args}')
```